# Calculate Term Frequency and Inverse Document Frequency for a very large data in Rstudio

Tags: r, corpus

I am doing a code trying to calculate the Term Frequency and Inverse Document Frequency (TF-IDF) for a very large file. The root file is indie_mar_23_0 which is a "character" class file I read from a .csv file. It has one column and 1500 rows. I then tokenize it Here are the codes

```
token_indie_mar_23_2 <- tokenize_regex(indie_mar_23_0, pattern = "\\s+", simplify = FALSE) 
token_indie_mar_23_2
```

The result look like this

[image]

I then run the corpus to create a Document term matrix

```
corp_mar_23_2<- Corpus(VectorSource(token_indie_mar_23_2))
tdmatrix_mar_23_2 <- DocumentTermMatrix(corp_mar_23_2)
inspect(tdmatrix_mar_23_2)
```

The result is a 32331 x 41182 matrix.

The TDM matrix i have is this

[image]

It seems like my matrix is not showing up 0 and 1. What is wrong with my case? And how do I caculate tf - idf?